# Alternative to using jest.setTimeout

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

Currently I've some tests (Jest + Supertest) configured in my NodeJS/Express/MongoDB app.
From my experience is can greatly differ when the server actually connects successfully with MongoDB (could take a couple of seconds).

My test where failing because it timed out after 5000ms (I believe this is Jests default timeout).

I was able to bypass this by defining a `jest.setTimeout(15000)` in the first part of the test which all together looks like this:

```
test('POST' + endpointUrl, async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(15000);

    const response = await request(app)
        .post(endpointUrl)
        .send(newTodo);

    ASSERTIONS
});
```

I'm wondering if this was the right way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an async function and must wait for the response, just use the `done` keyword as the test callback parameter.

```js
test('POST' + endpointUrl, async (done) => {
    const response = await request(app)
        .post(endpointUrl)
        .send(newTodo);

    ASSERTIONS
    
    done();
});
```

Or:

```js
test('POST' + endpointUrl, done => {
    request(app)
        .post(endpointUrl)
        .send(newTodo)
        .then(res => {
            ASSERTIONS
            done();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            fail(`It must be done, but catched because of: ${error}`);
        })
});
```

For more information, just check this topic: [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)